# Selecting count of child object collection in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a Customer object that has a child Orders collection.  I have this relationship set up in the mapping file with Orders being lazy-loaded.  Is it possible to lazy-load only the count of Orders instead of the entire collection?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could try using a formula (see nhibenate mapping reference) to execute sql code and get the value directly into a property.
this could use the count() function of your rdbms which avoids loading the entities at all.

Comment: Perfect... thanks!  The property I added to the Customer mapping was:

<property name="OrderCount" formula="(SELECT COUNT(*) from Order where Order.CustomerID = ID)" />